# Can I put a jquery handler in a constructor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm seeing if I can make some object oriented javascript and I have the following code.

When I went to move my jquery event handler into the constructor I became confused because now I have two *this* variables...

Am I approaching this incorrectly or is there a way to make it work?

```
function Dropdown(ddlname) {
    this.Value = 0;
    this.Selected = false;
    this.DDL = ddlname;
    this.Limited = false;
    this.SelectLast = function () {
        $(this.DDL + ' option:last').attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
    $(ddlname).change(function () {
        var v = $(this).val(); // <== ? 
        if (typeof v == 'number') {
            this.Value = v; // <== ?
            this.Selected = true; // <== ? 
        }
    });
    return true;
};
```

Comment: With the current code you will end up binding the same handler function to Val.DDL multiple times... What is in Val.DDL ?

Comment: changed it to 'ddlname', the id of the dropdown that the js class "wraps" (or so i'm attempting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign "this" from the context of your constructor to a local variable to be able to reference it from within your jquery event handler.

```
function Dropdown(ddlname) {
    this.Value = 0;
    this.Selected = false;
    this.DDL = ddlname;
    this.Limited = false;
    var hold = this;
    this.SelectLast = function () {
        $(hold.DDL + ' option:last').attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
    $(ddlname).change(function () {
        var v = $(this).val(); // <== ? 
        if (typeof v == 'number') {
            hold.Value = v; // <== ?
            hold.Selected = true; // <== ? 
        }
    });
    return true;
};
```

Comment: For this purpose it's fairly standard practice to name the variable either "self" or "that" - I prefer "self" to better reflect the usage. It's not obvious what "hold" means. Whatever you call it, I think it's nicer to put the declaration first in the function and then consistently use it instead of "this" rather than mixing between the two, saving "this" for use within functions that will be passed to jQuery (or other) code that will set "this" to something specific when calling those functions.

Comment: never really liked "that" for some reason. "self" works I guess

Comment: Yeah, I don't like "that" either because to me it sounds like it is referring to some other object, "*that* one over there", though it is used so commonly it's good to be aware of it. But I'll stick with "self".

Answer (score 2):

One trick i learnt from Marcelo Ruiz of DataJS team from microsoft is as follows:

```
function Dropdown(ddlname) 
{    
    var that = this;
    //rest of your code. now there is no confusion of this since you have that :) 
};
```

Not sure if this would help you. but just a trick i learned.

Comment: I prefer "self" rather than "that", so that the variable name reflects what it refers to: "that" implies some other thing. (Though I know use of "that" is quite common in this context, presumably because of the well-known phrase "this and that".)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you may, but you will need to call the class in the document ready function. I'm pretty sure it's bad practice.

You should consider passing the $ to the constructor or making a jQuery extension.